# Windows Server 2012 Essentials Dashboard client app won't start after .NET Framework update on client

Tags: .net, windows-update, windows-8, essentials-2012, windows-server-essentials

I'm running the 180-day trial of Windows Server 2012 Essentials. The client computer has Windows 8 Pro (64-bit) installed.

A few days ago, a security update for the Microsoft .NET Framework (KB2840632) was installed automatically via Windows Update on the client (twice; the first installation attempt failed, as seen in the Windows Update history), and since then the client app for the Windows Server 2012 Essentials Dashboard won't start anymore. After launching the app, there is some activity, but the Dashboard doesn't launch. In the Event Viewer on the client, these errors appear (in Dutch):

> ## .NET Runtime
>
> Toepassing: DashboardClient.exe
>
> Framework-versie: v4.0.30319
>
> Beschrijving: het proces is beëindigd als gevolg van een onverwerkte uitzondering.
>
> Uitzonderingsinformatie: System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException
>
> Stack:
>
> bij MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(System.Object, System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32, System.Delegate)
>
> bij System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeImpl()
>
> bij System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
>
> bij System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
>
> bij System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object)
>
> bij System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.Invoke()
>
> bij System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.ProcessQueue()
>
> bij System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.WndProcHook(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr, Boolean ByRef)
>
> bij MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr, Boolean ByRef)
>
> bij MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(System.Object)
>
> bij System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32)
>
> bij MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(System.Object, System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32, System.Delegate)
>
> bij System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.LegacyInvokeImpl(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority, System.TimeSpan, System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32)
>
> bij MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr)
>
> bij MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessage(System.Windows.Interop.MSG ByRef)
>
> bij MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessage(System.Windows.Interop.MSG ByRef)
>
> bij System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrameImpl(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherFrame)
>
> bij System.Windows.Application.RunInternal(System.Windows.Window)
>
> bij System.Windows.Application.Run()
>
> bij Microsoft.WindowsServerSolutions.DashboardClient.App.Main()

and

> ## Application Error
>
> Naam van toepassing met fout: DashboardClient.exe, versie: 6.2.9805.0, tijdstempel: 0x504a9f23
>
> Naam van module met fout: KERNELBASE.dll, versie: 6.2.9200.16451, tijdstempel: 0x50988aa6
>
> Uitzonderingscode: 0xe0434352
>
> Foutmarge: 0x000000000003811c
>
> Id van proces met fout: 0xa88
>
> Starttijd van toepassing met fout: 0x01cea0efc5324059
>
> Pad naar toepassing met fout: C:\Program Files\Windows Server\Bin\DashboardClient.exe
>
> Pad naar module met fout: C:\Windows\system32\KERNELBASE.dll
>
> Rapport-id: 104ddae5-0ce3-11e3-be93-00262d79dafa
>
> Volledige pakketnaam met fout:
>
> Relatieve toepassings-id van pakket met fout:

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Remove the .NET update until an adequate fix has been made?

Comment: When I try to uninstall the update, I get a non-specific error. I believe something went awry during the installation of the update, because I don't know someone else who has the problem also. `sfc /scannow` didn't help either.

Comment: Sorry no idea :( .. I tried doing some research and I'll I found was run the visual studio debugger type answers :(

Answer (score 0):

As it is only an evaluation, why not take a backup of the AD if needed and just rebuild? avoid that patch in future